# MLE error: initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite

Tags: r, modeling, mle

We simulated a data set and created a model.

```r
set.seed(459)

# seed mass
n <- 1000
seed.mass <- round(rnorm(n, mean = 250, sd = 75),digits = 1)

## Setting up the deterministic function
detFunc <- function(a,b,x){
  return(exp(a+b*x)) / (1+exp(a+b*x))
}

# logit link function for the binomial
inv.link <- function(z){   
  p <-1/(1+exp(-z))
  return(p)
  }

#setting a and b values
a <- -2.109
b <- 0.02

# Simulating data 
germination <- (rbinom(n = n, size = 10,
                        p = inv.link(detFunc(x = seed.mass, a = a, b = b))
                        ))/10

## make data frame
mydata <- data.frame("predictor" = seed.mass, "response" = germination)

# plotting the data
tmp.x <- seq(0,1e3,length.out=500)
plot(germination ~ seed.mass,
     xlab = "seed mass (mg)",
     ylab = "germination proportion")
  lines(tmp.x,inv.link(detFunc(x = tmp.x, a = a, b = b)),col="red",lwd=2)
```

When we check the model we created and infer the parameters, we get an error:

> Error in optim(par = c(a = -2.109, b = 0.02), fn = function (p) : initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite

```r
library(bbmle)
  mod1<-mle2(response ~ dbinom(size = 10,
                        p = inv.link(detFunc(x = predictor, a = a, b = b))
                        ),
             data = mydata,
             start = list("a"= -2.109 ,"b"= 0.02))
```

We're stumped and can't figure out why we're getting this error.

Comment: I haven't chased this down fully and won't be able to tonight, but my guess about what's happening is that `mle2` is adding `log=TRUE` to your `dbinom()` which is making some of the values `-Inf` and if you look through the code, it's actually calculating `minuslogl` which would produce a value of `Inf`.  I added `log=TRUE` into the function call above and got an error that `log` matched multiple arguments which corroborates the idea that they're adding that into the `dbinom()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're trying to fit a binomial outcome (which must be an integer) to a proportion.

You can use `round(response*10)` as your predictor (to put the proportion back on the count scale; `round()` is because `(a/b)*b` is not always exactly equal to `a` in floating-point math ...)  Specifically, with your setup

```
mod1 <- mle2(round(response*10) ~ dbinom(size = 10,
                    p = inv.link(detFunc(x = predictor, a = a, b = b))
                    ),
         data = mydata,
         start = list(a = -2.109 ,b = 0.02))
```

works fine. `coef(mod1)` is {-1.85, 0.018}, plausibly close to the true values you started with (we don't expect to recover the true values exactly, except as the average of many simulations [and even then MLE is only *asymptotically* unbiased, i.e. for large data sets ...]

The proximal problem is that trying to evaluate `dbinom()` with a non-integer value gives `NA`. The *full* output from your model fit would have been:

> Error in optim(par = c(a = -2.109, b = 0.02), fn = function (p)  :
> initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
> In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

It's always a good idea to check those additional warnings ... in this case they are all of the form

> 1: In dbinom(x = c(1, 1, 1, 0.8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.8,  ... :
> non-integer x = 0.800000

which might have given you a clue ...

PS you can use `qlogis()` and `plogis()` from base R for your link and inverse-link functions ...

Comment: I understand what you're saying the problem is, but I'm still having a hard time fixing it in the code.